# asp.net mvc and multiple models and modelbinders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nested, nested-forms

I wanna try to make this is as simple as possible.

Lets say I have a Project Model and a Task Model

I want to create a Project with 3 tasks assigned to that project in one single form

Whats the best way to do this??

Would the method simply receive a Project or what else do i need to have there.. will just saving the project (in repository) also save the related tasks?... 
In the view... do i need a viewModel.. Im confused. please help

```
public ActionResult Create(Project p){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would proceed:

```
public class TaskViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaskViewModel> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

then have a controller:

```
public class ProjectsController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var project = new ProjectViewModel
        {
            // Fill the collection with 3 tasks
            Tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(x => new TaskViewModel())
        };
        return View(project);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ProjectViewModel project)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // The user didn't fill all required fields =>
            // redisplay the form with validation error messages
            return View(project);
        }

        // TODO: do something with the model
        // You could use AutoMapper here to map
        // the view model back to a model which you 
        // would then pass to your repository for persisting or whatever

        // redirect to some success action
        return RedirectToAction("Success", "Home");
    }
}
```

and then the view (`~/Views/Projects/Create.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.ProjectViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProjectName)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ProjectName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ProjectName)
    </div>

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Tasks)

    <input type="submit" value="Create!" />
}
```

and the corresponding task editor template (`~/Views/Projects/EditorTemplates/TaskViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.TaskViewModel
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a collection of `Task` models to the `Project` model, and use a `foreach` loop to display the tasks, or repeat a partial view that knows how to display a single task.